# Falla en la sobrecarga del operador <<

Tags: c++, operador

he usado esta sobrecarga

```
template<typename T1>
ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, T1 tipo){

for (auto it= begin(tipo); it!=end(tipo);++it){
  os<<*it;
}  
return os;
}
```

para poder imprimir valores de un vector/lista, pero ahora no puedo imprimir valores string

```
int main(){
list<int> vec={2,3};
cout<<"hola"<<vec;
cout<<vec;
}
```

me sale error en "<<" del hola

alguien me puede decir que hice mal

Comment: Al hacer eso también estás reemplazando las sobrecargas existentes. El tipo del segundo parámetro debería ser más específico.

Comment: No vandalices la publicación

Answer (score 2):

Lo que deberías hacer es crear un operador específico para tu lista. Si el objeto `list` es una plantilla, entonces declara como tal la sobrecarga del operador:

```
template<class T>
std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & os, list<T> const& items)
{
    for (T item : items)
        os << item;

    return os;
}
```